# selecting multiple rows into single variable and to use it in where clause of another delete query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

As we can select multiple rows into single variable declared as some_table.rowtype in SQL. In the same way I want to fetch multiple row values of single column into a variable. So,

1. How can I declare it's variable type?
2. Can I use that in where clause?
3. Can I iterate through that variable(collection) values?

I want to do it in a stored procedure to delete one or more table records matching that variable values.

Comment: in theory there are some options... BUT you need to give specific and much more details... what have you tried ? what is not working ? what is your goal exactly ?

Comment: I want to do it in a stored procedure to delete one or more table records matching that variable values.

Comment: that doesn't say anything specific - to help you need to give some specific information... what have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried cursor. But using cursor I have to iterate through one by one and make delete or update statements. I want to do it with in clause and those in clause values should be available further in my procedure. Hope you understand

Comment: I understand BUT still not enough details - is the values a parameter of the the stored procedure ? how many values are there ? are thoes only IDs or complete rows in the collection ?

Comment: Values are result of SELECT INTO statement and those are ID's of table I am queried for. There may be hundred of values....

Comment: again: please show some code... what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE myTable.ID IN 
    (SELECT ID 
     FROM myOtherTable 
     WHERE myOtherCondition)
```

Comment: This works! but I need the values that can be used for other select or delete statements in a stored procedure.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't always use the 'IN' statement?

Comment: But if I have to run the DELETE over multiple tables, wouldn't the inner SELECT query run once for each DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE number_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

DECLARE
  my_number_table  number_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT some_column BULK COLLECT INTO my_number_table FROM some_table;
  DELETE FROM some_other_table WHERE some_column IN (
    SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(CAST(my_number_table AS number_table))
    );
END;
/
```